# django login url with param

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

a third party authentication requires api must to be called in the index view. for example, my domain is `zzd.com`, then they only provide api to `zzd.com`, which means we cannot have route specified for a signin view, which unable to put all login stuff into `zzd.com/login/`

however, index view is designed to shows some other important info primarily rather than login QR. hence we use a `login` button, when user click, switch the content to login QR.

here's the issue, I have following declaration in `settings.py`:

the index view serves all stuff in one template, including trending info, and login qr code if user is not authed. js looks like this:

```js
const url = new window.URL(window.location.href);
let mode = url.searchParams.get('mode');
if(mode === 'login'){
    showLoginQrCodeScanner();
}
```

which **login qr img would only show if `index/?mode=login` specified**, otherwise would display trending info instead. and my `settings.py`:

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGIN_URL = 'index'
```

the issue is that, I have some of my views `@login_required`, but, an anonymous user, would get redirected to the `index/?next=particular/url`, without the `mode=login` part, which does not show the qr in default.

**is there a way to declare login url with the param, for a much better user experience?**